# Resume airplay after device is on standby

Tags: airplay

I'd like to have my device constantly streaming airplay.
Now the challenge is, if the device is on stand by, it reverts to it's original state, which is not to stream.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, and have it stream to Airplay as soon as the device is back online?

Comment: explain stand by mode?

Comment: So you lock the screen, wait like 1 min, and it disconnects.

Comment: It goes in stand by mode because it thinks there is no activity to preserve battery! so what is your setting for that?

Comment: Right, so instead of wasting battery, how about it resumes air play after i wake the device up?

Comment: One way of doing that is to Turn Auto-Lock to off